# Значение требуемой переменной

Tags: java, android

У меня выходит ошибка, используя этот код

```
 holder.box.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        boolean newState = !arrEmps.get(position).isChecked();
        arrEmps.get(position).isChecked() = newState;
        Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(),
                arrEmps.get(position).getName() + "check" + newState,
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

строка ошибки

```
arrEmps.get(position).isChecked() = newState;
```

сообщение об ошибке

```
Error:(86, 48) error: unexpected type
required: variable
found:    value
```

Comment: Потому что это синтаксически неверная конструкция. У вас происходит вызов метода `isChecked()`, вызов метода может только что-либо возвращать, присвоить вызову ничего нельзя.

Comment: Что эта строка должна делать, по-вашему?

Comment: isChecked() вызывать метод, возвращающий значение

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я так понимаю, вам нужно для `arrEmps.get(position)` установить значение `check`, противоположное текущему. Метод `isChecked()` возвращает значение, для установки нужно использовать `setChecked(boolean)`

Вместо конструкции:

```
boolean newState = !arrEmps.get(position).isChecked();
arrEmps.get(position).isChecked() = newState;
```

Попробуйте так:

```
arrEmps.get(position).setChecked(!arrEmps.get(position).isChecked())
```